# Proposed Catch-all: What is duplicate content and how can I avoid duplicate content penalties?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, catch-all

At the time of this posting there are almost [4,000](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicate%20content) questions which concern duplicate content - some of these questions can be distilled to whether or not a specific practice will be qualified by Google as duplicate content.

Questions which poll for whether or not a given practice qualifies as duplicate content cannot be reasonably answered without a full accounting of Google's algorithm and are therefore not constructive, so this catch-all would be appropriate for questions of the form "is ___ duplicate content?" (as well as questions concerning the nature of duplicate content and how to correct cases where it appears as though Google is treating content as duplicated).

## Title

> What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it
> on my site?

## Description

> What does Google consider to be duplicate content?
>
> Will the way I am presenting my content result in a duplicate content
> penalty?
>
> How can I avoid having my site's content treated as duplicate content?

## Answer

> Google's [Duplicate Content](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359) webmaster guide defines duplicate
> content (for purposes of search engine optimization) as "substantive
> blocks of content within or across domains that either completely
> match other content or are appreciably similar".
>
> Duplicate content is typically penalized (either excluded from or
> given a lower priority in search results) by search engines because it
> is often associated with [scraper sites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scraper_site) which copy content
> wholesale and simple [article spinning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamdexing#Article_spinning) techniques which generate
> "new" content by selectively replacing words in existing content.
>
> Google's guide goes on to list the following as examples of duplicate
> content:
>
> > - Discussion forums that can generate both regular and stripped-down pages targeted at mobile devices
> > - Store items shown or linked via multiple distinct URLs
> > - Printer-only versions of web pages
>
> Whether or not a given piece of content or technique will be
> considered duplicate content by a search engine is debatable without a
> full accounting of the algorithms used to rank and index sites,
> however, you can avoid penalties associated with duplicate content on
> your site by observing the following guidelines:
>
> 1. Ensure that content is only accessible under one [canonical URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization)
> 2. If your site must return the same content under multiple URLs (e.g. for a "print view" page) [specify a canonical URL manually with a link
>    element](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) in the document header
> 3. In cases where your site returns similar content based upon parameters encoded in the URL (e.g. sorting a product catalog)
>    [exclude the URL parameters](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1235687) in Google Webmaster Tools

---

**10/14 Edit:** [Posted to main](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Answer (score 1):

Less noise? I'm all for it. Good job!